# Python script runs on command line, but not when called from PHP with arguments

Tags: python, php, linux

I have an apache web server that is intended to accept registrations if they pass the required checks and then add them to a bin file. The python script works exactly how it's supposed to if called from the command line. I know the python file is fine. But for some reason, when I submit the arguments via the php file, the python script never completes, unless it fails do to finding a duplicate user. I get a response code if a user already exists. If I try to give a new user but a UUID that already exists, or if I submit information I know will pass all the way to completion, I get nothing. It doesn't complete because it doesn't save the new user, but it will from the command line. I cannot figure it out.
**The php file**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["USER"])){
  $USER = $_GET["USER"];
  if(isset($_GET["UUID"])){
    $UUID = $_GET["UUID"];
    if(isset($_GET["KEY"])){
      $KEY = $_GET["KEY"];
      if(isset($_GET["SIG"])){
        $SIG = $_GET["SIG"];
        //$command = 'python3' . ' ' . '/scripts/register.py' . ' ' . $USER . ' ' . $UUID . ' ' . $KEY . ' ' . $SIG;
        //echo exec($command);
        echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /scripts/register.py $USER $UUID $KEY $SIG");
      } else {
        print 4;
      }
    } else {
      print 3;
    }
  } else {
    print 2;
  }
} else {
  print 1;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**and the python file**

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
from nacl.encoding import HexEncoder
from nacl.signing import VerifyKey
import binascii
import codecs

from base64 import b64encode #trying to get pyacl to work

#y = int(x, 16)

# error_codes
# 0 = success
# 5 = USER already exists
# 6 = UDID already exists
# 7 = signature verification failed
# 8 = invalid parameter length
# 9 = server error
error_code = 0 # we start with 0

USER = sys.argv[1].upper() # 64 hex chars
UDID = sys.argv[2].upper() # 32 hex char
KEY = sys.argv[3].upper()  # 64 hex chars
SIG = sys.argv[4].upper()  # 128 hex chars

MSG = (USER + UDID + KEY)

#if not os.path.isfile('/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin'):
#  print("creating file")
#  MSG = '322F965A2919F46725DECE842EB487FC569656D59BF3E1D35CC33CF8A9DCDFEC3517E355F47642C897F42AB1A186591A40E4D0D79B88BD30DC91376017DF57004A4995345185FE97EC1404B29E01086B'
#  bytes_str  = binascii.unhexlify(MSG)
#  print(MSG)
#  with open("/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin", "wb") as f:
#    f.write(bytes_str)

if len(MSG) == 160:
  if os.path.isfile('/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin'):
    filesize = os.path.getsize("/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin")
    users = float(filesize / 80)
    if users.is_integer():
      users = round(users)
      with open("/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin", "rb") as f:
        user_step = 0
        match = 0
        for i in range(users):
          f.seek(user_step * 80)
          current_user = binascii.hexlify(f.read(32)).decode().upper()
          if current_user == USER:
            match = 1
            error_code = 5
            break
          else:
            current_udid = binascii.hexlify(f.read(16)).decode().upper()
            if current_udid == UDID:
              match = 1
              error_code = 6
              break
            else:
              user_step += 1
        if match == 0: # after checking all file data or abandoning
          verify_key = VerifyKey(KEY, encoder=HexEncoder)
          signature_bytes = HexEncoder.decode(SIG)
          validity = binascii.hexlify(verify_key.verify(MSG, signature_bytes, encoder=HexEncoder)).decode().upper()
          if validity == MSG:
            error_code = 0
            with open("/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin", "rb+") as f:
              f.write(binascii.unhexlify(MSG))
        #else:
          #print("Registration rejected")
    else:
      error_code = 9
  else:
    print("Creating new file...")
    verify_key = VerifyKey(KEY, encoder=HexEncoder)
    signature_bytes = HexEncoder.decode(SIG)
    validity = binascii.hexlify(verify_key.verify(MSG, signature_bytes, encoder=HexEncoder)).decode().upper()
    if validity == MSG:
      error_code = 0
      with open("/var/www/html/src/registrations.bin", "wb") as f:
        f.write(binascii.unhexlify(MSG))
else:
  error_code = 8

#print("Error code:", error_code)
print(error_code)
```

It seemed like a permission issue but moving the location of the files or giving file ownership to apache didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you considered generating debug output at varied branches with python?

Comment: _the python script never completes_ Add a bunch of `print()` statements so you can trace the execution of the code.  Add a print at the top of every `if` block, and the top of every `else` block (and make sure that every `if` has an `else`).  And of course make each print message unique so you can tell where each message came from.

Comment: I know it stops after checking user. It's designed to send a response code for everything so the user knows they're accepted, or if it's rejected the mobile app can use the response code to tell them why it was rejected. I tried adding more prints but it doesn't tell me anything really. For some reason it looks like apache is failing to write the file and/or run pynacl. These are some higher level things but a server should be able to save a user after verifying they signed the data that was sent. Especially considering the data is being written to a file anybody should have access to read.

Comment: I do 95% of my work on purpose-built microcontrollers in C++, but I do alright with python. This doesn't appear to be a code issue, but rather a behind the scenes issue that's preventing the php from completing the python script, and that kind of issue just isn't in my expertise. I can't really get any debug info aside from it stops after checking user but everything works perfectly when called from the terminal. If I comment out all file and pynacl items it does complete in php but both of them need commented out.